# Is "é" and "á" non-ASCII character?

Tags: characters, non-ascii

I have tryed to open steam and it came up with an error something like this: "Cannot open file with non-ASCII characters in the folder path." I have come up with a suspicion of two folders that the folder path contains. The two folders contained the characters "á" and "é." Can somebody answer my question?

Comment: á and é are not ASCII characters

Answer (score 3):

Letters included in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) are limited to A-Z, both lower- and uppercase, without accents. *á* and *é* are not ASCII characters.